# Adding Math to Plots

Tags: graphics, formatting, matex

I have several formulas I would like to place at specific coordinates in a `Graphics` object I have already created. I need to be able to choose bold or not as well as how large to make it. I am unsure how to control the size of the text as well as why *Mathematica* will not place it. Specifically, it continues to try to evaluate my text. One of the objects I wish to place on the plot is (since it won't let me post a picture)

$$M^\mu = \oplus_{\lambda \ge \mu} \,m \, \lambda_\mu \, S^\mu$$

However, *Mathematica* continues to try to evaluate the direct sum rather than just place it at say the point (0,0).

Here is the code I am trying at the moment:

```
Graphics[{Style[HoldForm[M^μ == \!\(*UnderscriptBox[(StandardForm[⊕]), (λ ≥ μ)]\) m Subscript[λ, μ] S^μ], Medium], FormatType -> StandardForm}]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at `HoldForm`.

Comment: I had tried hold form, but it still does not like the format. Here is the code I am trying at the moment. Graphics[{Style[HoldForm[M^\[Mu] == 
\!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(StandardForm[\[CirclePlus]]\), \(\[Lambda] \
\[GreaterEqual] \[Mu]\)]\) m Subscript[\[Lambda], \[Mu]] S^\[Mu]], 
   Medium], FormatType -> StandardForm}]

Comment: Blast from the pre-MaTeX era.

Comment: @Syed  yes. I was wondering why no answer was saying to use Matex then I looked at the date when this was asked.  Strange that WRI still does not want to bundle MateX in Mathematica so it becomes built-in command.

Answer (score 10):

You may be interested to know that you can enter formatted (e.g. subscript, superscript) expression within a String, delimited by `"` `"`.  Further, you can select elements of this string and size, position, and color them, using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+(cursor key), and the formatting menu (or keyboard shortcuts).  You can also use `Eplilog` and `Text` to place this string inside a `Plot` graphic:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the string is displayed, by default, in `TraditionalForm`, but you can use `StandardForm[string]` to override this.

Answer (score 6):

You might try the *Mathematica* `Graphics` primitive `Text` as a way to solve your problem. This allows very fine adjustment of position.

Here is an example:

```
Graphics[{Circle[], 
   Text[Style[(M^μ == Subscript[S, (l ≥ u)]), Bold, 16, 
        FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], {0., 0.}, {0., 0.}]}, 
   ImageSize -> Small]
```

which gives the result

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Create the `Graphics`, then go to Graphics -> Drawing Tools, click the Mathematica Text button on the palette (looks like a Σ), click on the graphic, and type your formula as you normally would.  Use Format -> Size to set the size.

I just made this using this method:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the type of thing I was looking for, simple too! It's been so long since I've used the Graphics tool without having to program something I'd forgotten all about it. Thank you!

Comment: But annotations added with the Drawing Tools are evanescent: re-evaluate the input and the annotations will no longer be in the new output.

Answer (score 2):

I use this method all the time,  but I'm far, far, far from a "good" user.

But this method lets you put math ANYWHERE,  in a graphic, a table, etc.

Easier to do than explain in a text response.

Type what you want into a text cell.

Show expression on the cell.

Eg....  I typed  the following into a text cell..

[image]

Then "Show Expression" on the cell.... you get this....

```
    Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[
  RowBox[{"y", "=", 
   RowBox[{
    RowBox[{"2", 
     SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]}], "-", 
    SqrtBox["b"]}]}], TraditionalForm]],
 FormatType->"TraditionalForm"]], "Text"]
```

Copy the entire expression and paste into an input cell

Wrap this in Text[DisplayForm [  expr   ]

So, for the above,  you get

```
  Text[DisplayForm[FormBox[
  RowBox[{"y", "=", 
   RowBox[{
    RowBox[{"2", 
     SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]}], "-", 
    SqrtBox["b"]}]}], TraditionalForm]]]
```

You can now use this "Text" package anywhere....

As an example

```
    Graphics[{

  Circle[],

  Text[DisplayForm[FormBox[
       StyleBox[
         RowBox[{"y", " ", "=", " ", 
            RowBox[{
               SubscriptBox["log", 
                 FractionBox["1", 2]], "x"}]}],
         FontSize -> 36, FontColor -> Red], TraditionalForm]], {0, 
    0}]

  }]
```

Comment: Tom, I haven't tried this method yet.  Have you tried mine?  Where would one prefer this over styling a String?